# Object Collider sometimes not eorking

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

Been fixing the collider but end up no success given. i set the ball's collider which is greater than the 'container inner radius' but somehow the rotator could "push" the ball into the container
[Video Sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zj9Hp31KqLM)

Comment: Are the box colliders set to constant?

Comment: Set your calculation type to one of the `Continuous` modes (Speculative or Dynamic)

Comment: Thank vakore,  I will try it out later see whether it works

Comment: @Immersive both ball and the tank's Rigidbody already set to Collision Detection "Continuous Dynamic" but same error happens